# How do I configure API keys for exponent create-react-native-app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

I have been following create-react-native-app steps, and then looked at the docs. It talsk about the `exp.json` file which does not appear using create-react-native-app. However I want to use MapView into the app, but don't know how to proceed. Let's assume I want to get it working on Android, but after I will need it on iOS too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need exp.json when you use CRNA . I figured this out yesterday when I was trying to create a standalone app. You put those codes in app.json  You may want to read this [forum post](https://forums.expo.io/t/exp-json-wasnt-there/394/2)

It should look something like this.

```
{
  "expo": {
      "slug": "food-loca",
      "sdkVersion": "15.0.0",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "orientation": "portrait",
      "primaryColor": "#cccccc",
      "icon": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-us-standard/rnplay/app-icon.png",
      "notification": {
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "loading": {
        "hideExponentText": false
      },
      "packagerOpts": {
        "assetExts": ["ttf", "mp4"]
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems good! I was thinking that they were actually the same thing. Could you please give me an example on how the file would look? It is the only thing I am missing.